# How to step into WCF Rest service from .NET client app?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, rest

I am developing a solution in Visual Studio 2010 that has a WCF RESTful service hosted in IIS (actually Cassini at this point) and a prototype ASP.NET MVC client.  I have everything communicating but cannot step into the service when debugging the client.

I have a "service agent" class that is used by my controllers to work with the service.  The service agent uses the following code to make the actual service calls:

```
var factory = new WebChannelFactory<IServiceContract>("theEndpointConfigName");
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();

var result = channel.CallTheService();
```

I can set a breakpoint on the last line but hitting F11 does not step me into the service as I would expect.

Both projects exist in the same solution and I have verified that the service is being called correctly by modifying the response data.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you attach VS to IIS worker process?

Comment: I've never had to when working with a WCF service within the same solution before.  Is this a difference because the service is using REST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually stumbled upon the answer.  I'll give thanks to Christian for unknowingly steering my in the right direction.  Your statement about the debuger attaching to one or the other process but not both got me thinking.  It occurred to me that I had the web project set as the only start-up project in my solution.  As a lark, I decided to try adding my WCF service application in the start-up list.  Viola!  That's all it took!

So now I have both projects starting up.  I've changed the setting in my WCF Service app so it does not show a page on start-up.  And now everything works as I would expect.

Thanks for the prod in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

The Visual Studio debugger cannot step across a process boundary. You can either attach to the client process or the server process, but not both at once.

Here are some suggestions:

- First debug the client code. If the bug is not there, then reproduce the bug a second time, but debug the service code instead of the client code.
- Create two separate solutions for debugging purposes, one containing only the client projects, and the other only the service projects. You can then run both solutions in two IDE instances side by side.
- Add unit tests. It's a lot easier to find a bug in the service if the "client" is a bare-bones unit test method instead of your full client.

Comment: Unfortunately this is supposed to be a quick-and-dirty proof-of-concept so I'm really not following TDD at this point.  I will do so when (if) we get into true development on the solution.  what I don't understand is that I have no problem stepping into my service operations when using WCF with SOAP.  Is REST the problem?

Comment: And I'm also thinking ahead. Being able to step into the service is a nice feature to have when trouble-shooting issues.

Comment: To be honest I've never bothered with the "quick-and-dirty" stage of service development, I always go straight to IIS and put in the unit tests on day one, so I can't offer any advice on that front, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at below article of CodeProject to get idea of How to Debug WCF REST Servive.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/213007/Debug-WCF-REST-Service